# Rotator conflicting with MailChimp integration.

Tags: javascript, conflict, mailchimp, rotator

The rotator on the home page www.furnaceworldco.com is conflicting with the mailchimp/newsletter sign up form. On an internal page I can click submit on the newsletter sign up and it works; however if filling out the form from the homepage, the submit button does not work.

I've enabled "SC jquery" and get an error that prevents the rotator from loading. Any suggestions?